# Expand input hiding adjacent buttons on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap page with two buttons and an input next to each. When the user focus' the input I want to fade out the buttons and expand the input to full width, and likewise shrink it and fade in the buttons when the user blurs the input.

As you can see in the small (sorry) GIF below, it works find when it is blurred, however when it is focused the input expands too fast so gets pushed onto the line below.
[image: Current]

This is my code:

**JS**

```
$("#message").focus(function(){
    $('#disconnect').fadeOut("fast");
    $('#send_picture').fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).parent().addClass("col-md-12").removeClass("col-md-8");
    console.log("You focused the message input...");
});
$("#message").blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("col-md-8").removeClass("col-md-12");
    $('#disconnect').fadeIn("fast");
    $('#send_picture').fadeIn("fast");
    console.log("You unfocused the message input...");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" id="disconnect" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Disconnect</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" id="send_picture" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Send a picture</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message and hit enter..." type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your addclass line in a callback to the fadeout line for example    $('#send_picture').fadeOut("fast", function(){$(this).parent().addClass("col-md-12").removeClass("col-md-8");});

Answer (score 0):

position `absolute` the button elements and the input inside a `relative` positioned container div, that will insure that they don't get in each others way, you can also play with z-index and [delays](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) after that